How to delete vertices that are “behind”?
I have an object at (0, 41, 0). I want to delete the back half so the object looks the same from the camera at (0, 0, 0), but will cost less to 3D print.
Perhaps I need to select and then delete vertices that are “behind”? But I do not know if this is the best approach, or how to do it.
I am happy to do this in Python, but I do not know where to start from. Any suggestions?
The Blend file is available here:

Here are three views (top, right, front) of an example object:




Would you agree with a solution based on GeometryNodes ? If so, Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

@StefLAncien
Yes to Geometry Nodes. I have included a link to the Blend file in the original post.
Thanks.

Option 1
Static solution, easy, jagged edges.

In edit mode, from the angle you want to look (you can look from the camera view by pressing numpad 0 or clicking the little camera on the right side of the 3d view)
Turn "OFF" x-ray and wireframe. Keep solid mode
Make a big rectangle with the mouse to select (the back will not be selected)
Invert the selection (ctrl+i or menu "Select"->"Invert")
Delete

Option 2 - Geometry nodes with some smoothing
I was able to make a geometry nodes setup that smoothens the selection a little, but it's not perfect. This kind of smoothing sounds complicated. Improvint it requires some new ideas.

Main nodes

Stores the visibility attributes based on the camera position
Separates the visible faces
Those faces that are near the visitble faces and have one point sticking out not connected to a visible face are changed to make this point go between the two neighbor points, removing the sharp corner of this face


Store visibility
Here the magic happens

For each point of the geometry, raycasts this point towards the camera (a small offset is added so the point doesn't hit itself)
If there is a hit, this point is behind and is invisible
Stores the "Visible" points
Then evaluates the visible points on face domain (some faces get partial visibility values)
Turns the partial visibility values into whole values (we want to keep the partially visible faces)
Goes back to the point domain and store the value as "NearPoint" (these points would be enough if you don't try to smoothen, the nodes could end here in this case),
For smoothing, we go again from "NearPoint" to the face domain (this interpolates the values so the neighbor faces become partially visible) and store the "NearFaces" (these faces are adjacent to the partially visible faces)

A value of 1 means the face is visible or partially visible
A value of 0.75 means one point of the face is not connected to any partially visible face
A value of 0.5 means two points and 0.25 three points.




File


Thank you. @DanielMöller That works, but the selection is very rough and jaggedly at the thresholds between front and back. Are there any settings I can adjust? If not, this is where I am hoping Geometry Nodes or Python might fine-tune the selection.

@PaulStGeorge , updated with a geometry node option that does a partial smoothing. (Covering all smoothing cases is more complicated than my time allows)

Wow, that does it. It should be an add-on. I have two questions, but they might answer each other. Q1. What is Epsilon? Q2. It would be great to have a numerical threshold (between visible and invisible) one could adjust -- so the borders at the top and bottom of the volume slide towards or away from the camera (wax and wane). I am guessing this is your Epsilon, is it? If so, could it be an input for the ‘Greater Than’ node and called ‘Threshold’? This last suggestion is just for transparency and understanding, and if you are going to publish your masterpiece.
@DanielMöller

Epsilon is a small tolerance. Since we are dealing with computer math (float values), exact numbers rarely exist, there is always a little error and we need to take that into consideration. Specifically in the raycast source position, I used epsilon to start the ray just a little away from the object (otherwise it results in 100% hits)

Example: when we want to compare something with zero, it's safer to check not if it's equal zero, but between ±epsilon

@PaulStGeorge, it's not simple to have this threshold. It's a new idea. For checking things, leave the camera view and look around. Use Viewer nodes to check the values.
